# Losing data while writing with BufferedWriter

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I want to read a big ASCII text file (20GB) line by line and copy a part of these lines in a separate file. The following example code looses data when writing in the output file. I tested the Reader with some printlns and its working as expected. I tried to increase the buffer of the BufferedWriter, but no improvement. Also flush() didn't work. The output file in this case should be around 40MB.

I hope you can help me,
Greeting Tim

```
public void split() throws Exception{
    BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));      
    BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));

    for(int i=0;i<700000;i++){
        String tempString = inStream.readLine().trim();
        if(doOtherStuff(tempString,i)){
            break;
        }
        outStream.write(tempString);
        outStream.newLine();
    }
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();  
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a for loop and not a while loop?

Comment: The information of how many lines i need to copy is read in with the first line of the file. I thought this is not relevant to the problem so in shortend it a bit.

Comment: You don't tell us the specifics of what data is lost or where, and you don't know why your code is misbehaving, so ***all*** is relevant. My experience has been that regardless of how you're figuring how many lines the file has, you're far better off using a while loop and letting the BufferedReader let you know when its run out of lines to read. It's much more idiot-proof.

Comment: Ok i will implement the while loop to make sure I only read Data if there is some. But the problem is with the writing of the data. If I add a System.out.println(tempString) before I write the data, I can see that all lines are read in properly. Each line(->tempString) contains between 30 and 40 characters. The output file stops in the middle of line, so i would say the problem occures while outStream.write(tempString). Also there are no Exception thrown

Comment: Probably just me after one or two funnies in the past, but I always call Flush() before closing the stream, given you are losing < buffer size off the end of the file.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Your tip did the trick. I thought a close would block till all is written... Thanks a lot

Comment: Well it was an educated guess given the number of times that assumption has shot me in the foot. Close() doesn't automatically force a flush, because there are scenarios where you might not want that, "garbage" in the buffer for instance.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Yes it does, for all classes derived from FilterOutputStream, which includes BufferedOutputStream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @EJP, Why did adding Flush() fix his problem then? Don't do Java, which is why it was a guess, you do have to do it in .net and Delphi though

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No idea. There are lots of possibilities. He observed his symptoms incorrectly, or he wasn't calling `close()` at all, or he was closing the underlying stream not the `BufferedOutputStream`, or ...

Comment: Could be me then, used to .net, standard practice would mean closing either ends up closing both.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant this?

```
for (;;) {
    String tempString = inStream.readLine();
    if (tempString == null)
        break;
    tempString = tempString.trim();
    if(doOtherStuff(tempString,i)){
        continue; // Skip writing, continue with next line
    }
    outStream.write(tempString);
    outStream.newLine();
}
```

Without the null test, EOF throws an exception.

Comment: You are right, a EOF check is necessary. But in my current case its not the problem, as I have checked the read in data with System.out.printlns

Comment: readLine() does not throw an exception at EOF. It just keeps returning null forever.

Comment: @EJP in the question code a `readLine().trim()` was done, which throws a NullPointerException - when EOF before loop counter.

Comment: @JoopEggen Exactly. `readLine()` does not throw an exception. It returns `null`. `((String)null).trim()` throws an exception. Nothing to do with `readLine()` whatsoever.